# I got a syntaxerror on an argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax, discord.js

```
async function msge(){
  client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === `${call}status`) {
      msg.reply('The aqi in Bucharest is ' + await printf())
        .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  })
  return console.log("Worked")
}
```

This is the function that gets the error and i can't get why.
This is the error code: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `await` in here like that:

```
msg.reply('The aqi in Bucharest is ' + await printf())
                                       ^
```

Await expects the scope it runs in to be annotated with `async`.
Just put the `async` keyword next to msg:

```
client.on("message", async msg => {
                     ^
```

Alternatively, you could use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Since you already use it here. You could also just add another `.then()`;

```
function msge(){
  client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === `${call}status`) {
      msg.reply('The aqi in Bucharest is ')
        .then(printf) // <-- you may adjust this to match your signature
        .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`))
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  })
```